# How to remove databank entries after running tests in Playwright?

Tags: testing, playwright

Lets say I run an e2e test that will create a document. The test will then create "Document01". The problem is now that the document "Docoument01" now exist in the database. How can I remove this entry "automatically" after the test is finished?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A few high-level options:

1. Run the e2e tests against a refreshed database copy each time. Might only be possible for trivially small databases.
2. Use a node database library to do the deletion via sql in an "after all" block.
3. Create a delete function within your web application/api and use that to delete the record.